# How to check if/else statement for multiple textboxes and variables?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows form with 5 textboxes on it. In these textboxes the user can fill in 3 values (500,555 or 610).  Every value needs to be multiplied with a constant. For every value there is another constant. Below is my code for one textbox (txtSectie1).

In stead of copying this code 5 times (for every textbox) I think there is a way to use a loop so I don't have to copy the code 4 times, but I can't figure it out. For each of the 5 text-boxes I want to store a value in a variable (dblGewichtPaneel1 to dblGewichtPaneel5). All the textboxes and variables have the same name, only the last character changes from 1 to 5.

Comment: The usual way to solve problems like this is to put your data into an associative array and use a loop.  Then you only need one `if` statement. (well, maybe two in your case).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Robert. Do you have a link to a page where I can learn how to create an associative array? I am just a beginner... Thanks!

Comment: An associative array is just a data structure that can hold Key/Value pairs and allow you to you iterate through it.  A Sorted Dictionary would do nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:

1. Put the entire code in to a method which accepts TextBox and Panel as input parameters.
2. Put all your textboxes and panels in a list and then run a loop on the list, repeatedly calling the method created in point 1.

Solution 2:

1. Run a loop 1 to 5, wrapping the above code.
2. Find the controls using

   ```
   Textbox control = (TextBox) this.Controls["txtSectie" + i]; //this being Form or container control
   if(control!=null)
   {
       //do work
   }
   ```